# CSS - How to force second div to another row when first div overflows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, word-wrap

I have two divs placed next to each other of equal width. When the text in the first div overflows to a second line, I would like the second div to be placed below the first div- doubling the width of each div. Is this possible in CSS?

I have tried using flexboxes but I don't know where to go from here.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell" style="background-color:pink;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </div>
  <div class="cell" style="background-color:lightblue;">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure as to what you're asking could you possibly explain that in a different way? I'm a bit confused because how I interpret that is you want the childrens height to be 100% of the parents height, so when one child grows and expands the parent the other one does also, but I'm interpreting another part of that as saying you want second line to wrap out side the div, below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Both divs have to be `min-width: 50%` and the last div has to be `flex: 1`. The parent div should have `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#cell1 {
    background-color: pink;
    min-width: 50%;
}
#cell2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="cell1">
        Lorem ipsum dods Ut eniasdfasdf
    </div>
    <div id="cell2">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the container and `flex-grow: 1;` on the items. (view snippet in full screen and adjust browser width)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell" style="background-color:pink;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </div>
  <div class="cell" style="background-color:lightblue;">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the behavior I am looking for. The second div should be on the same row as the first if the first does not overflow (in that case, both divs should be 50% width). This condition is not satisfied by your code.

Comment: Ah, so you want the 2nd to wrap the next, just not the first. Glad you got it figured out.